# Importing a postgres database to Heroku using a pg_dump file

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I am using this guide from the Heroku documentation: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#import

It details how to import in a postgres to heroku so it can be used in a Heroku app.

I am at the end and trying to use the command heroku
`pg:backups:restore '<SIGNED URL>' DATABASE_URL`

What should be used as the DATABASE_URL?

I have run heroku config and copied and pasted that DATABASE_URL, but I get the following error:
`Unknown database: 'my plugged in url'. Valid options are: DATABASE_URL`

Answer (score 0):

Use `DATABASE_URL`, literally:

```
heroku pg:backups:restore '<some-signed-url>' DATABASE_URL
```